# Android widget Textview size for smaller screens

Tags: android, textview, widget

In my widget layout file, I have set textview text sizes and all my content fits inside the widget. When I launched on a smaller phone (320x480) a lot of the text was cut off and was not visible on the widget. How can I account for smaller phone sizes and define smaller textview sizes?

Comment: post your code, so that we can understand your mistake or issue & give a solution

Comment: try to use different dimensions for different mobile screen size, and your problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dimens  to set textsize based on phone's screensize.

[image]

Look in above image I made 4 dimens for different screen sizes.
In dimens(w820dp) I wrote following code.

```
<resources>
<!--include 7" and 10" devices -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
<dimen name="item_image_size">60dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

While in dimens.xml(sw600dp) I wrote following code as per requirements.

```
<resources>
<!-- For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger) -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="item_image_size">54dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/5962715) and
add

```
android:maxWidth="size"  //size- the number more than 1
```

this in your textview layout